# Php Composer import project as dependency

Tags: composer-php

My project is based on another "core" project i've built.

I'm currently adding this "core" project to my project using git subtree command.

Is there a way that I can add the project as a dependency ? Can I add it as a (private) package ?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish. Using your local git repository as dependency for another local git repository? Could you provide your current `composer.json`?

Comment: Simple answer: Yes! I think a good answer depends on some more information. Where is your core project hosted? Is it local or in a git repo or at github? Does your project already make use of composer? Is it a problem if your core project is within a `/vendor/` folder inside your current project?

Comment: @Peh Yes, to project is hosted in a remote repo (bitbucket) and has its own composer. I currently use git subtree since it allow me to change the core project from the current project but it can be the same in the vendor as well (i think at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `core` project already has a `composer.json` you can require it form any other project.

Here is an example for requiring from a bitbucket repo:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

For more see the composer docs at [using private repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories)